# Laravel - exclude current email from unique validation

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use unique on an email address in Laravel 5.5 validation like this..

```
   $rules = [
            'email' => 'email|unique:users,email,
    ];
```

This is working and is checking the 'users' table in the 'email' column

But if the email address is the same as the currently saved one then this also fails validation.

Is there a way I can add an exception rule to the validation to ignore $user-email?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`unique` rule takes a third parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-unique): a record to ignore, see "Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID".

Pass in the ID of the record you do not wish to be included in the `unique` test, e.g:

```
$rules = [
    'email' => 'email|unique:users,email,' . $user->id
];
```

Comment: How will I get the `$user->id` here ?

Answer (score -1):

## THIS IS AN EASY SOLUTION

**Just add $this->route('id') as the third parameter**

if your route was defined like this:

```
Route::put('{company}', 'CompanyController@update')
        ->name('update');
```

then your parameter name is "company"

So in your FormRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'url' => [
            'required',
            'url',
            'unique:companies,url,'.$this->route('company') ?? 0
        ],    
    ];
    // dd($rules); << check yourself

    return $rules;
}
```

This FormRequest works the same for insert or update.

this line will instruct to ignore "0" in case of insert

`$this->route('company') ?? 0`